# Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

Tags: python, windows, ssl, scikit-learn, installation

```
C:\Users\deypr>pip3 install sklearn

Collecting sklearn

  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/sklearn/

  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/sklearn/

  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/sklearn/

  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/sklearn/

  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)': /simple/sklearn/

  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/sklearn/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/sklearn/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)'),)) - skipping

 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sklearn
```

I am getting this error whenever trying to install any **python3** package.

1. What could be the possible reasons?
2. How to fix it ?

Comment: did you try reinstalling Python3?

Comment: I did. Is it some connection issue by any chance?

Comment: which version of pip are you using? try this `pip --version`

Comment: 9.0.1 
and Python3 as well @Vallie

Comment: I'm getting this error within Visual Studio Code, but installing from the terminal is totally fine... I'd guess that rules out the existing suggestions about the network or the cache

Comment: you may check the proxy settings of VSCode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was a network issue. It worked totally fine when I moved to a different network.

Answer (score 53):

Regarding the error/warning message in the question's title:

> Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

You can fix it by removing the pip cache, e.g. on Ubuntu:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! Thanks :)

Comment: Is this safe? That is, will some cached pip3 data not be lost and make pip3 act less than optimal.

Comment: No one should name anything `cache` if it couldn't be deleted.. (usually caches like this work the way if it's not in the cache pip has to download it, then it can cache some stuff it thinks might be useful to be faster next time)

Answer (score 4):

Its scikit-learn not sklearn on pypi. Check the [documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-the-latest-release)

Try:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

Comment: Actually `sklearn` aliases to `scikit-learn`.  They both mean the same thing: https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/ - However, `sklearn` is indeed deprecated so `scikit-learn` is now the recommended formula on `pip`.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the pip command with **--no-cache-dir**.

For example:

```
>>> pip install keras --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be that you have a lower python version. For instance, you install `tensorflow` on python 3.6.0 and you'll get `Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored` for many libraries that come with `tensorflow`.

But if you use python 3.8.0, all is good.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods
one removes cache

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
```

Other install package with --no-cachw-dir

```
pip install --no-cache-dir Package_Name
```

if it is not solved restart your working machine