# Downloading requirements.txt from GitHub

Tags: python, github, pip, package, requirements.txt

I trying to download `requirements.txt` from my repo in GitHub

I use `pip install -e git+https://github.com/GabrielCoutz/Problema-Chiado#egg=requirements.txt` and this is returning:

```
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project requirements.txt from git+https://github.com/GabrielCoutz/Problema-Chiado#egg=requirements.txt.
```

How i can create `setup.py` and what i have to put in?

Comment: Installing only `requirements.txt` does not make any sense. Please explain **in details** what you are trying to do!

Comment: @KlausD. i just want to install some packages in this txt, i still learning (clearly) how to use ```GitHub``` and things about ```install packages```, i already solve my problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GabrielCoutz/Problema-Chiado/main/requirements.txt
```

-e is for local installs for developing, for example. Check this:
[What is the use case for `pip install -e`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609943/what-is-the-use-case-for-pip-install-e)

Comment: it should be 
`pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GabrielCoutz/Problema-Chiado/main/requirements.txt
`

Comment: It worked =D but a warning appears ```WARNING: Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored``` should i worry?

Comment: maybe a network issue, if persist rm -rf ~/.cache/pip (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671215/cache-entry-deserialization-failed-entry-ignored )

Comment: Ok, i will see more about this later, but for now, thanks bro <3333